# Load images/sounds with LWJGL/Slick2d applet

Tags: java, applet, embedded-resource, lwjgl, noclassdeffounderror

I've got an issue when I try to load images or sounds on Applet. I use LWJGL for applet and Slick2d to load images/sounds.
But when I launch the applet with Netbeans, there is no problem...
There is the code I use to load a sound :

```
public class Files {
    public static Audio sound;

    public static void load() {
        try {
            sound = AudioLoader.getAudio("WAV", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("/snd/Tir1-16b.wav"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Files.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        System.out.println("loaded with success !");
    }
}
```

And there is the HTML Page :

```
<applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar" codebase="." width="800" height="600">

    <!-- The following tags are mandatory -->

    <!-- Name of Applet, will be used as name of directory it is saved in, and will uniquely identify it in cache -->
    <param name="al_title" value="appletloadertest">

    <!-- Main Applet Class -->
    <param name="al_main" value="myapps.MyApps">

    <!-- List of Jars to add to classpath -->
    <param name="al_jars" value="lwjgl_applet.jar, lwjgl.jar, jinput.jar, lwjgl_util.jar MyApps.jar">

    <!-- signed windows natives jar in a jar --> 
    <param name="al_windows" value="windows_natives.jar">

    <!-- signed linux natives jar in a jar --> 
    <param name="al_linux" value="linux_natives.jar">

    <!-- signed mac osx natives jar in a jar --> 
    <param name="al_mac" value="macosx_natives.jar">

    <!-- signed solaris natives jar in a jar --> 
    <param name="al_solaris" value="solaris_natives.jar">

    <!-- Tags under here are optional -->

    <!-- whether to use cache - defaults to true -->
    <!-- <param name="al_cache" value="true"> -->

    <!-- Version of Applet (case insensitive String), applet files not redownloaded if same version already in cache -->
    <!-- <param name="al_version" value="0.1"> -->

    <!-- Specify the minimum JRE version required by your applet, defaults to "1.5" -->
    <!-- <param name="al_min_jre" value="1.6"> -->

    <!-- background color to paint with, defaults to white -->
    <!-- <param name="boxbgcolor" value="#000000"> -->

    <!-- foreground color to paint with, defaults to black -->
    <!-- <param name="boxfgcolor" value="#ffffff"> -->

    <!-- logo to paint while loading, will be centered, defaults to "appletlogo.gif" -->
    <!-- <param name="al_logo" value="appletlogo.gif"> -->

    <!-- progressbar to paint while loading. Will be painted on top of logo, width clipped to percentage done, defaults to "appletprogress.gif" -->
    <!-- <param name="al_progressbar" value="appletprogress.gif"> -->

    <!-- whether to run in debug mode -->
    <!-- <param name="al_debug" value="true"> -->

    <!-- whether to prepend host to cache path - defaults to true -->
    <!-- <param name="al_prepend_host" value="true"> -->

    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
  </applet>
```

And there is what the console log shows when I launch the HTML page with the applet :

```
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.run(AppletLoader.java:906)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/newdawn/slick/util/ResourceLoader
    at myapps.Files.load(Files.java:24)
    at myapps.MyApps.init(MyApps.java:32)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.switchApplet(AppletLoader.java:1330)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader$2.run(AppletLoader.java:909)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

null certainly means there the variable Audio is null. That's also means the file is probably not found ... So I tried to put the directories "snd" and "sprites" on the applet directory, and also on the .jar of my applet but nothing happens...

Can anyone helps me ? I searched a lot of time trying too find this kind of problem on many forums but no one helped me ...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError`  Fix that first.  What Jar is `ResourceLoader` located in?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer.
I fixed the problem of `NoClassDefFoundError` by adding "slick.jar" in my html page like as follow :

```
<param name="al_jars" value="MyApps.jar lwjgl_applet.jar, lwjgl.jar, jinput.jar, lwjgl_util.jar slick.jar">
```

But now I have another problem :

```
This occurred while 'Initializing real applet'
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" ".\snd\Tir1-16b.wav" "read")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" ".\snd\Tir1-16b.wav" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.exists(Unknown Source)
    at org.newdawn.slick.util.FileSystemLocation.getResourceAsStream(FileSystemLocation.java:52)
    at org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ResourceLoader.java:61)
    at myapps.Files.load(Files.java:24)
    at myapps.MyApps.init(MyApps.java:32)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.switchApplet(AppletLoader.java:1330)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader$2.run(AppletLoader.java:909)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've read a lot of things about this problem, and I tried to sign my MyApps.jar by using theses commands :

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias key
keytool -export -alias key -file cert.crt
jarsigner MyApps.jar key
```

And the signer has worked because now I can see files "KEY.RSA" and "KEY.SF" on my META-INF of the MyApps.jar.
But the problem still here...

I need some help, I just don't understand this issue ...

Thank you !

Comment: *"But now I have another problem :"*  That should be the subject of (research re applets and files/URLs, and possibly) a new question.

Comment: Hi, yeah it's another problem but it still a problem of loading images or sounds. I searched a lot about this but I really don't find anything... Everybody says it's because the applet isn't signed but mine is signed.

Comment: This one should be about the NCDFE.  I am not spending further time on it.